# How to replace() multiple @var in same pole, with text from another table column?

Tags: sql-server, replace

I'm working on this project right now.

My problem is: in table 1 I see column `DynamicField` with a lot of `@var`. I.e

```
@var=textofvar;@var2=textext
```

and so on.

What I need to do is find this `=text` and replace (not update) each `@var` I will find in table 2 column `MailSubject` with it.

My current problem (excluding code style and optimization) is when I use cursor as you can see below, only one `@var` is changed atm, and on next line first `@var` is still not being replaced only the second it is.

What am I doing wrong? Ofc I can do it with function easier (I already did so code of function will be below) but this time I feel a need of making this with cursor if this is possible at all.

Current code:

```
SELECT 
    t.id,
    SUBSTRING(t.items, 1 , CHARINDEX('=',t.items)-1) as zmienna,
    SUBSTRING(t.items,  CHARINDEX('=',t.items)+1, LEN(t.items)) as wartosc    
INTO 
    #temp 
FROM 
    (SELECT id, items 
     FROM MailSendingEvents
     CROSS APPLY dbo.split(DynamicField, ';')) t 

DECLARE @id int
DECLARE @zmienna nvarchar(100)
DECLARE @wartosc nvarchar(max)

DECLARE cursor_replace CURSOR FOR 
     SELECT
         id, zmienna, wartosc
     FROM
         #temp

OPEN cursor_replace
FETCH NEXT FROM cursor_replace INTO @id, @zmienna, @wartosc

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    DECLARE @replace nvarchar(max)

    IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM MailEventTypes 
              WHERE MailSubject LIKE '%' + @zmienna + '%')
        SELECT REPLACE(t.MailSubject,@zmienna, @wartosc) AS MailSubject
        FROM MailEventTypes t
        INNER JOIN MailSendingEvents e ON e.ID_MailEventTypes = t.Id 
        WHERE e.id = @id

    FETCH NEXT FROM cursor_replace INTO @id, @zmienna, @wartosc
END;

CLOSE cursor_replace
DEALLOCATE cursor_replace
DROP TABLE #temp
```

Solved with this function:

```
ALTER FUNCTION dbo.textreplace 
    (@tresc nvarchar(max), @zmienne nvarchar(max))
RETURNS nvarchar(max) AS
BEGIN
    IF @zmienne NOT LIKE '%@%'
        RETURN @tresc

    WHILE CHARINDEX('@', @tresc) > 0 AND LEN(@zmienne) > 0 
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @varstart int = CHARINDEX('@', @zmienne)
        DECLARE @varend int = CHARINDEX(';', @zmienne)
        DECLARE @vardiff int = CHARINDEX('=', @zmienne)                 

        DECLARE @varname nvarchar(max) = SUBSTRING(@zmienne, @varstart, @vardiff - @varstart)
        DECLARE @vartext nvarchar(max) = SUBSTRING(@zmienne, @vardiff+1, @varend - @vardiff - 1)        
        DECLARE @varall nvarchar(max) = SUBSTRING(@zmienne, CHARINDEX('@', @zmienne), CHARINDEX(';', @zmienne))     

        SET @tresc = REPLACE(@tresc, @varname, @vartext) 
        --print @tresc
        SET @zmienne = REPLACE(@zmienne, @varall, '')
    END

    RETURN @tresc
END

SELECT dbo.textreplace(t.mailsubject, e.DynamicField)
```

Comment: "in table 1 I see column DynamicField with a lot of @var" - that's a poor design.

Comment: "but this time I feel a need of making this with cursor " - erm, say what?

Comment: yep well... poor desing is not my fault, about cursor i was curious if it's possible at all but i guess it is not, anyway thx for reply